# Error message in R when trying to do delayed entry survival analysis with the survfit function

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to redo some survival analysis that I did a few years back with an updated dataset (longer patient follow-up).
This time my delayed entry analysis does not work.

```r
fit <- survfit(Surv(time0rem/365.25,time1/365.25, primevstatusOK, type="mstate")~1, data=drem)
```

Variables:

- `time0rem` = entry time in days (date of cancer remission)
- `time1` = censoring time in days (date of relapse, competing event or last follow-up)
- `primevstatusOK` = event (relapse, competing event or last
  follow-up)

I get the following error message:

> Error in survfitCI(X, newY, weights = casewt, stype = stype, ctype =
> ctype,  :    an id statement is required for start,stop data

Does anyone knows what this means? I have googled but cannot find this exact error message in other posts.

I have set all values as numeric and checked for missing values.

And I have checked that for all patients entry time is larger than `0` and smaller than censoring `time1`.

If I conduct the analysis without delayed entry, there are no problems:

```r
fit <- survfit(Surv(time1/365.25, primevstatusOK, type="mstate")~1, data=drem)
```

Comment: Can you share sample of data? For example, can you edit your question add the result of `dput(head(drem))`?